# Finding an efficient algorithm for computing a part of an unsorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, big-o

The question is:

Given an array of n unsorted elements. For each of the following value of k, suggest
an efficient algorithm in terms of worst case complexity for computing the k minimal
values where:

a. k = 30

b. k = n/3

c. k = logn

For each case, give a short description of the algorithm and brief analysis of the worst
and the best case complexity.
Edit: We don't have to sort the unsorted array, as long as we compute k in an efficient way, it's fine.

Ok, so I am not sure of this at all,

a)
For k = 30, I would suggest that we will find the minimal number 30 times, for the first time we will run n times, for the second time it will be n - 1, until n - 29. so way we can compute the 30 lowest numbers in O(n), (right?)

b)
Thinking about just sorting it in an nlogn worst case sorting algorithm (heapsort or mergesort, depends on if the user will or will not want to use extra space) and then just compute the first n/3, so I can do this in O(nlogn) steps.

c) Thought about making a min heap from this array, so to heapify it will cost me O(n), after that I need to use the deleteMin of the heap (that will cost me O(logn) exactly logn times so it will be n + logn^2 which means O(n) (right?)

So you see, I've thought about this, still not sure of my answers.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If we're ignoring constant factors, then this is sort of a strange question, because regardless of whether the output must be sorted (you should clarify this), there's one algorithm that works optimally for all k.

Comment: It is not a must to sort this array, if there isn't a better solution then nlogn so it will be easier to sort it

Comment: How about simply walking through the items and putting them in a sorted datastructure? That means `n*log(k)` inserts worst case, best case you just have `n` because it's already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient algorithm we could use to compute the k minimal values would involve the use of heaps. We would first begin by building a minimum heap. When we build a minimum heap we are creating a complete binary tree.
To create the heap we would follow another algorithm. We begin by adding an element to the bottom of the heap. We then compare this element with its parent and if it is less than the parent we can stop. If not we change the elements and repeat. Building the minimum heap tree has a worst case running time of O(n)  (Also possibly O(logn) depending on the type of implementation).

After this is done the minimum element will be at the root of the binary tree and we can therefore remove it from the top. However, if we are looking for the k smallest elements we must “heapify” the graph each time after we remove a minimum element (k times). When we heapify we are rearranging our current tree so that it becomes a heap once again. A heapify operation has a worst case running time of O(logn) and we are doing it k times so the worst case running time of this part is O(klogn).

When we combine the two operations our final worst case time complexity is                O(n + klogn).

For each case the worst case running time complexity would remain the same.

Comment: Could you spell out the worst case time complexities for a), b), and c)? What about `best case complexity`?

Answer (score -2):

For any algorithm you need to sort the 1st 30 items.  The 31st item you only have to compare against max existing number.  If it is larger you do nothing 1 comparison).  If it is smaller, then you have to compare against 30/2 (average). Then remove largest.

Comment: What about b) and c)?

Comment: To sort with N/2 you use a bubble sort.  N/3 is similar to bubble but you compare three items instead of 2.  LogN is a binary tree sort.

Comment: (Sorry for the urge to down-vote. Your answer does not show worst and best case complexity assessments for a), b), and c). Your comment seems to mix up `N/2` and n² - wait, you seem to be looking for algorithms with an expected complexity of the form specified for *k* in the question, but *k* is something entirely different: the count of minimal element values to determine.)